# C++ Look up table that returns an existing array of type struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a number of existing arrays of a struct type

```
typedef struct Patterns
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

The arrays are named as follows

> arr0, arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, etc.

I am passed an integer value and would like to use it to look up the array that is needed and copy it to a temporary array.

i.e. int 0 corresponds to array arr0 and so on.

I've tried to use the "map" method but i run into the error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" when assigning the arrays to the integer keys

```
std::map<int, Patterns[]>map1;

map1[0] = arr0;
map1[1] = arr1;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to quickly look up which array i need to utilize?

Comment: Did you consider a `std::map<int, std::vector<Pattern>>`?

Comment: If you are using an array, why not continue with an array of pointers?

Comment: Can you provide your current arrays definition?

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] please, otherwise your question is not answerable.

Comment: @jbh  Do all the arrays have the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use vector not array. You cant really create a map of pattern[].

You should have

```
vector<vector<Pattern>> arrays;

arrays[0] = arr0;
arrays[1] = arr1;
```

etc.